# Spring Test with @RestClientTest and @FeignAutoConfiguration not working

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, rest-client, openfeign

I have the following configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
public class Application {
```

```
@FeignClient(name = "theclient")
public interface TheClient {
...
```

```
theclient:
  ribbon:
    listOfServers: http://server:8080
```

And have the following test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@RestClientTest(TheClient.class)
@ImportAutoConfiguration(
        classes = {
                RibbonAutoConfiguration.class,
                FeignRibbonClientAutoConfiguration.class,
                FeignAutoConfiguration.class
        }
)
public class TheClientTest {
...
```

The error I get is `Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: theclient` as if the `application.yaml` was not read. If I add, however, a `config.properties` file with the `theclient.ribbon.listOfServers=http://server:8080`, the tests works and passes.

With `@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.yaml")` I see in the logs `propertySourceLocations = '{classpath:application.yaml}'` but I will get the same error.

I also tried to disable ribbon, by adding:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    loadbalancer:
      ribbon:
        enable: false
```

but it won't work.

I appreciate your input and help.

Comment: Is the client visible in the Service Registry that you communicate with?

Comment: @OlgaMaciaszek, I am not using a service registry, the documentation says the client name is matched with what is configured on application.yaml. I suspect the test configuration ( `... @RestClientTest... @ImportAutoConfiguration`) is messing up with how spring picks up the client.